# Module-level functions to instantiate classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class-method

Is it a good practice to instantiate a class using a module-level function in the same file? I use YAML to create instances of the object.

This is an example of what I mean.

```python
#file.py
def newfile(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return File(f.read())

class File(object):

    def __init__(self,content=None):
        self.content = content  

#main.py
import newfile
file = newfile("/path/to/file.txt")
```

Another option could be to create a class method to do the same.

```python
#file.py
class File(object):

    def __init__(self,content=None):
        self.content = content  

    @classmethod
    def new(cls,path):
        with open(path) as f:
             return cls(f.read())

#main.py
import File
file = File.new("/path/to/file.txt")
```

The reason I need to do something like this is the fact that I load objects from YAML to read and write lots of files, so I would like to do this in an organized, clean way. I have to set the attributes to optional values, since sometimes I also need to use empty objects.

Comment: This is pretty much the stated use case for class methods: alternate constructors for a class. (Something like `from_file` would be a better name, though.)

Comment: I wouldn't do this all the time, but I've seen things like this done sometimes in `__init__.py` or a `config.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what a class method is for: providing an alternate constructor for your object.

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, content=None):
        self.content = content

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        with open(path) as f:
            return cls(f.read())
```

However, a potentially cleaner method would be to have `__init__` neither a file path nor raw data, but instead a file-like object. Then, your class only needs to support a single use case, namely reading from a file-like object.

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.content = f.read()
```

Now, your caller is responsible for either opening a file:

```
with open(path) as fh:
    f = File(fh)
```

or creating some other file-like object:

```
import StringIO

f = File(StringIO.StringIO("some data here"))
```